# Optimization of 3 variable function when all variables have value

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization

I have the function

[image]

In this function, all variables x, y, and z have a value. The goal is to optimize the function, but only one variable can be increased. Based on the values of the variables, what is the way to decide which variable should be increased, such that the function grows the most?

So far I have tried to look at the gradient of the function, but have yet to come up with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take the partial derivatives in each direction, we get the following:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & = & \frac{y(1 - z)}{\left(xy + (1 - z)(1 - x)\right)^2} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} & = & \frac{x(x - 1)(z - 1)}{\left(xy + (1 - z)(1 - x)\right)^2} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} & = & \frac{-xy(x - 1)}{\left(xy + (1 - z)(1 - x)\right)^2}
\end{eqnarray}$$

These all have the same denominator, which thanks to being squared will never be negative, so assuming it's non-zero we can just compare the numerators, which are all polynomial in $x, y, z$. None of them is obviously the winner, so for any given value of the variables you just evaluate all three and the one with the biggest value is the one that will have the greatest increase.